# Create default in constructor function if no argument is passed - javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, arguments, default

I have the following:

```
class example {
   constructor (arg) {
      this.value = arg.value
   }
   print () {
      console.log(this.value);
   }
}

var new_example = new example  ({
   value: 12,
})

new_example.print();
```

How do I set a default value where say value = 10, such that, if no argument was given, it would print 10. I.e.:

```
var newer_example = new example ({
})
```

I've tried things like:

```
class example {
   constructor (arg) {
      this.value = (arg.value || 10)
   }
   print () {
      console.log(this.value);
   }
}
```

And:

```
class example {
   constructor (arg) {
      this.value = ("undefined" != arg.value || 10)
   }
   print () {
      console.log(this.value);
   }
}
```

But can't find anything that works.

Comment: A problem with your first solution is that it will assign 10 anytime `arg.value` is falsey, not just undefined. E.g., it was assign 10 if `arg.value` is 0, or an empty string, even though you may want those values.

Comment: Another problem with the first solution is that if `arg` is undefined, `arg.value` will throw an exception.

Comment: what do you mean throw an exception?

Comment: It will throw an exception because `undefined` does not have a `.value` property. Try running `undefined.value` in your console and you'll see the error message "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use defaults for the arguments, and you can use destructuring with further defaults for the object properties to support both `new example()` and `new example({})`:

```js
class example {
   constructor ({ value = 10 } = {}) {
      this.value = value
      // Note: You could also use Object.assign(this, { value }) which
      // can become useful once you have more values in your object
   }
   print () {
      console.log(this.value);
   }
}
```

Comment: I found a reference that helped me understand your code more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value

Answer (score 1):

You can use built in `arguments` and check like this:

```js
class example {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.value = arguments.length > 0 ? arg.value : 10;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

new example().print();
new example({ value: 12 }).print();
new example({ value: false }).print();
new example({ value: '' }).print();
```

You could also (close to what you had), verify `arg` is defined:

```js
class example {
  constructor(arg) {
    if (arg && typeof arg.value !== "undefined") {
      this.value = arg.value;
    } else {
      this.value = 10;
    }
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

new example().print();
new example({ value: 12 }).print();
```

Or if all falsey values aren't needed you can do the above with shorthand:

```js
class example {
  constructor(arg) {
    this.value = (arg && typeof arg.value === 'number') ? arg.value : 10;
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}

new example().print();
new example({ value: 12 }).print();
new example({ value: 0 }).print();
new example({ value: false }).print(); //value false is lost
```

Comment: I like your second solution. Is there a way to make it shorter? I have a lot of values.

Comment: if you don't need falsey values as pointed out, you could do `this.value = (arg && arg.value) || 10;`

Comment: I need to account for values that equal 0

Comment: @CherryDT answer is far superior

Comment: thanks, their answer is working well, I'm just trying to figure out how it works exactly

Answer (score 0):

```
class example {
   constructor (arg) {
      this.value = (arg.value || 10)
   }
   print () {
      console.log(this.value);
   }
}
```

This code works for me. I think your problem is on the sixth line
`console.log(value)` this should be `console.log(this.value)` (you forgot `this.`). Common mistake!

Comment: Incorrect -- you can't use the `arg.value || 10` expression for all values of `arg` because for when `arg` is null, you will get a runtime error during evaluation of `arg.value` -- attempt to use a property on null value. Fixing this with minimal change would be using the [`?.` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) instead of `.` -- `arg?.value || 10`. The latter will work even if `arg` isn't passed and is thus `undefined`, or when `arg` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring for cleaner neater code:

```js
class example {
    constructor (arg = {['value']:3}) {
        this.value = arg.value
    }
    print () {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
}
```

`print` called on the object created without passing anything to the constructor, will have the console output `3`:

```js
var newer_example = new example()
newer_example.print(); /// Console prints `3`
```

Comment: Why the convoluted object expression `{ ['value']: 3 }` instead of the simpler equivalent `{ value: 3 }`?